# Integrating over the unit circle contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How can I integrate $\frac{\ln{z}}{z}$ over the unit circle contour?
I failed to find the residue at z=0, and I have also tried to parametrize as shown below
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\ln{z}}{z}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\theta}{e^{i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=-\int_0^{2\pi}xdx=\frac{-(2\pi)^2}{2}=-2\pi^2$$
I used $z=e^{i\theta}$, and I chose ${(0,2\pi)}$ since the contour path fully rotated around the origin. The problem is, I am sure this is wrong. My resource says this contour integral is 0, can someone tell me why I am wrong, or correctly evaluate this?

Comment: How do you define $\ln z$ on the unit circle? It can’t be made continuous, so you are going to have to branch the function. Which branch you use affects the integral.

Comment: Why are you sure that integral is wrong? It looks right for one branch of $\ln z.$

Comment: With the usual branch cut on the negative reals, you’d get $$-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x\,dx=0.$$

Comment: $\ln(e^{i t}) \ne i t$ for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$ with the usual branch cut of $\ln$.

Comment: I haven’t learned anything about branches yet, thanks for helping